# How to fix Error when checking input error?

Tags: image-processing, keras

I'm trying to train a GAN for generating samples of images and ground truths for a semantic segmentation task, however I'm getting an error regarding the shape of my input. From the errors it seems that it expects my input arrays are 4 dimensions however I believe that the shape I need (5 dimensions) is required for the problem at hand.

The shape of my tensors is (64, 2, 128, 128, 3)
64 for the images in the batch, 2 for either the image or ground truth, 128, 128 for the image dimension, and 3 for RGB channels.

My generator looks like this:

```
def build_generator(input_dim, output_size):
    """
    生成器を構築
    # 引数
        input_dim : Integer, 入力ノイズの次元
        output_size : List, 出力画像サイズ
    # 戻り値
        model : Keras model, 生成器
    """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=(input_dim)))
    unit_size = 128 * output_size[0] // 8 * output_size[1] // 8
    model.add(Dense(unit_size))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    shape = (output_size[0] // 8, output_size[1] // 8, 128)
    model.add(Reshape(shape))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(3, (5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
    return model
```

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_9_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 2, 128, 128, 3)
```

Is there anywhere I can change so that my generator will accept these 5 dimensional array inputs?

Comment: Why do you need to input the ground truth to the generator? You should really just input a 4D tensor, so you have to separate image and ground truth into two tensors.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro So far my implementation generates a synthetic image, but I'd like it to generate a corresponding synthetic ground-truth for that image. Is that possible with the separation of tensors?

Comment: Of course it is possible, it makes no sense to require ground truth input to genrate synthetic ground truth output.